# Whats SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault in Qt

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault

I have a Qt program which displays the data it receives over UDP.
It works fine for around 30 seconds but after a while it gives Segmentation Fault and crashes. This 30 seconds is also not fixed.

I used the debugger and got this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x003c6fd4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
```

Can anyone tell me where the error might be?

Comment: If you download and use the debug version of libQT, you should be able to see in the stacktrace exactly where it crashes. Hint, install the `qt-debug*.rpm` if you're on an rpm system.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means your program has tried to access memory that doesn't belong to it. Basically, you have  a pointer that contains an invalid value somewhere in your code - a common source of this error is dereferencing a NULL pointer.

Comment: @wic Never think like that until you have exhaustively proved there is no bug in YOUR code.

Comment: There was no bug in the Qt code obviously it was a silly mistake on my part.

Comment: I get the same error and still can't understand what I should do.

Answer (score 2):

You need a debugger (and make sure you have binaries with debug information) -- check the stack trace at the crash site. I'd pretty much assume your own code will appear somewhere, and this is the point to start with. Check allocations, buffer sizes …

Comment: Yah the debugger was of great help. Havent used it much before.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have allocated array that you are assigning data to.

I have constantly had this error for not allocating.

Example I have used:

```
char* m_tempBuff;
*(int*) m_tempBuff = i;
```

Latter changed to, and it worked:

```
char m_tempBuff[sizeof(int)];
*(int*) m_tempBuff = i;
```

Best of luck! :)